# fwrite fails depending on previous fwrite

Tags: c, pointers, bitmap, fwrite

I have a problem with some fwrite that fail in way I do not understand.

In this piece of code both fwrite fail and give tmp = 0.

```
  if ((file = fopen(filenameout, "wb")) != NULL)
  {
    bmpheader->filesz += bmpdib->bmp_bytesz;
    bmpdib->bmp_bytesz *= 2;
    bmpdib->height *= 2;
    tmp = fwrite(bmpheader, sizeof(bmp_header_t), 1, file);
    tmp = fwrite(bmpdib,    sizeof(bmp_dib_t),    1, file);
    tmp = fwrite(bmpdata1,  bmpdib->bmp_bytesz,   1, file);
    tmp = fwrite(bmpdata2,  bmpdib->bmp_bytesz,   1, file);

    fclose(file);
  }
  else
    return 1;
```

But if I comment one single line of code everything goes fine:

```
      if ((file = fopen(filenameout, "wb")) != NULL)
      {
        bmpheader->filesz += bmpdib->bmp_bytesz;
//        bmpdib->bmp_bytesz *= 2;
        bmpdib->height *= 2;
        tmp = fwrite(bmpheader, sizeof(bmp_header_t), 1, file);
        tmp = fwrite(bmpdib,    sizeof(bmp_dib_t),    1, file);
        tmp = fwrite(bmpdata1,  bmpdib->bmp_bytesz,   1, file);
        tmp = fwrite(bmpdata2,  bmpdib->bmp_bytesz,   1, file);

        fclose(file);
      }
      else
        return 1;
```

I double checked every detail in my code:

- bmpdata1 and bmpdata2 contain valid bmp bitmap data, they produce both a correct image if used alone.
- bmpheader and bmpdib are data structures read from a valid bmp file and they are untouched until my code.
- all files have been opened in binary mode "rb" for input and "wb" for output.
- bmpdata1 and bmpdata2 are copies of the same image, so their byte size is identical.

The goal of my code is to write an image plus a modified copy of it to obtain a final image twice higher than the original one. The original bitmap is a 570 x 363 x 24bit bmp image.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If this is a release (optimised) build then you can't assume that `tmp` is valid - the compiler can see that it is not used so may just optimise it away. Add a temporary printf after each fwrite to stop this happening and to be certain that you're chasing the right problem.

Comment: Hi Paul. No, it'a debug release.

Comment: When you comment out that code then the two last calls to `fwrite` write half as much data. Are bmpdata1 and bmpdata2 big enough? What is the `errno` after `fwrite` returns 0?

Comment: You are right Art. That's a stupid error. I used the modified byte size value to write a unmodified size bitmap. I feel I just embarrassed myself. Thank you a lot. Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem. Thanks to Art.

```
  if ((file = fopen(filenameout, "wb")) != NULL)
  {
    bmpheader->filesz += bmpdib->bmp_bytesz;
    bmpdib->bmp_bytesz *= 2;
    bmpdib->height *= 2;
    tmp = fwrite(bmpheader, sizeof(bmp_header_t),   1, file);
    tmp = fwrite(bmpdib,    sizeof(bmp_dib_t),      1, file);
    tmp = fwrite(bmpdata1,  bmpdib->bmp_bytesz / 2, 1, file);
    tmp = fwrite(bmpdata2,  bmpdib->bmp_bytesz / 2, 1, file);

    fclose(file);
  }
  else
    return 1;
```

I erroneously used the updated bitmap data size to write each part of the final image. The resulting image has double the height because it is composed bay two stacked images which are written each in a separate 'fwrite' operation with half of the resulting bitmap data size each.